# Convert ByteString into numpy array of 1s and 0s

Tags: python, numpy

I am wanting to turn a bytestring, for example `b'\xed\x07b\x87S.\x866^\x84\x1e\x92\xbf\xc5\r\x8c'` into a numpy array of 1s and 0s (i.e. the binary value of this bytestring as an array of binary values).

How would I go about doing this?

I tried using `np.fromstring` and `np.frombuffer` but neither did what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unpackbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html). Per the docs:

> Unpacks elements of a uint8 array into a binary-valued output array.

```
import numpy as np

b = b'\xed\x07b\x87S.\x866^\x84\x1e\x92\xbf\xc5\r\x8c'

bits_array = np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.uint8))
print(bits_array)
```

outputs

```
[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe numpy gives you a way to do this directly.

You can do this in several steps:

```
x = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.ubyte)
y = np.array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128])

z = np.sign(x[:,None] & y[None,:])
```

This now gives you a 16x8 array of 0's and 1s with your data.  You can resize it if you want flat data.

```
z.resize(len(data) * 8)
```

Comment: I think `y` should be flipped. Otherwise, you get `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` for `\x12` instead of `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: Also, you could use `.reshape(-1)`, `.flat`, or `.flatten()` in place of resize with an explicitly compute length

Comment: @Brian: It wasn't clear which order the OP wanted the output bytes, since no sample output was given. I've seen both big-endian and little-endian interpretation of bytes.

Comment: @Brian Watch out that `np.ndarray.flatten()` produces a copy of the input rather than the view that `np.ndarray.reshape(-1)` or `np.ndarray.ravel()` would return. `np.ndarray.flat` returns an iterator-like object so that is quite different from the others.